# Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '([T.T])'

Tags: arrays, swift, list, types, append

```
protocol UtimesListResponseProtocol:HandyJSON{
    associatedtype T
    var slide: Int {get set}
    var top: String {get set}
    var bottom: String {get set}
    var hasMore: Bool {get set}
    var list: [T] {get set}

    func add<M:UtimesListResponseProtocol>(data:M)
}
extension UtimesListResponseProtocol{
    mutating func add<T:UtimesListResponseProtocol>(data:T){
        slide = data.slide
        top = data.top
        bottom = data.bottom
        hasMore = data.hasMore
        list.append(data.list)
    }
}
```

I want to add a method of adding arrays in the protocol, but it doesn't seem to work. What should I do, mainly because the data types in array are also generics, what should I do

Comment: because your list is type of T and you are trying to add M, remove associatedType, change1 - var list: [UtimesListResponseProtocol] {get set}, change2 - list.append(contentsOf: data.list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues: first of all, you need to call `append(contentsOf:)` if you want to append an `Array` to another. Secondly, you need to make sure the generic type parameters match, since `Array`s in Swift can only contain elements of the same type.

```
extension UtimesListResponseProtocol{
    mutating func add<List:UtimesListResponseProtocol>(data:List) where List.T == T {
        slide = data.slide
        top = data.top
        bottom = data.bottom
        hasMore = data.hasMore
        list.append(contentsOf: data.list)
    }
}
```